# react-native-background-task Expected to run on UI thread

Tags: react-native

I am trying to sync data capture offline with an online api, I periodically run an background task using react-native-background-task to retrieve offline data and sync the data with an online api.

[react-native-background-task error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAYSv.jpg)

```js
// This component below triggers the background task on load 

import { sync, clean } from "../../services/market/forms/tasks";
import MediaWorker from "../../services/market/forms/MediaWorker";

let worker = new MediaWorker();

BackgroundTask.define(async () => {
  console.log("Life's good");
  
  // loads data from db and sync them with the online service
  await sync(worker);
  
  // delete synced data from the db and end task
  await clean();
});

export default class Onboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  async checkStatus() {
    const status = await BackgroundTask.statusAsync();

    if (status.available) {
      // schedule the background task
      BackgroundTask.schedule();
      return;
    }

    const reason = status.unavailableReason;
    if (reason === BackgroundTask.UNAVAILABLE_DENIED) {
      Alert.alert(
        "Denied",
        'Please enable background "Background App Refresh" for this app'
      );
    } else if (reason === BackgroundTask.UNAVAILABLE_RESTRICTED) {
      Alert.alert(
        "Restricted",
        "Background tasks are restricted on your device"
      );
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkStatus();
  }

  render() {
   // Not important for the question
  }
}

// snippet for sync function
export const sync = async worker => {
  const formInstances = await loadFormInstance();

  if (formInstances.length) {
    // Send Textual data
    const formInstancesText = filterFormInstances(formInstances, "text");
    postFormTextInstance(formInstancesText);

    // Get form image data and post
    const formInstancesImage = filterFormInstances(formInstances, "image");
    formInstancesImage.forEach(worker.send);
    // Get form audio data and post

    const formInstancesAudio = filterFormInstances(formInstances, "audio");
    formInstancesAudio.forEach(worker.send);

    // Get form video data and post
    const formInstancesVideo = filterFormInstances(formInstances, "video");
    formInstancesVideo.forEach(worker.send);
  } else {
    console.log("Nothing to sync");
    BackgroundTask.finish();
  }
};


// snippet for clean function
export const clean = async () => {
  const formInstances = await loadFormInstance();
  if (formInstances.length) {
    const toBeDeleted = new Set();
    formInstances.forEach(formInstance => {
      const fields = formInstance.fields;
      let allSynced = true;
      for (let index in fields) {
        const field = fields[index];
        if (field.synced === false) {
          allSynced = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (allSynced) {
        toBeDeleted.add(formInstance.instanceID);
      }
    });

    toBeDeleted.forEach(deleteFormInstance);
  } else {
    console.log("All tasks finished");
    BackgroundTask.finish();
  }
};
```

[Adb log(Used for monitoring background activity)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAYSv.jpg)

**Note**: Background task runs successfully a lot of time, but fails occasionally with the red screen shown when the app is build in debug mode.
In release mode, the app completely crashes.

[Stack trace generated by Crashlytics in production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzfD6.png)

Comment: It turns out react-native-background-task version wasn't compatible with my react-native version, i upgraded from 0.48.1 to 0.51.0 which requires react 16.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, it turned out react-native-background-task version wasn't compatible with my react-native version, i upgraded from 0.48.1 to 0.51.0 which requires react 16.0.0